# Kubectl get nodes return "the server doesn't have a resource type "nodes""

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I installed the Kubernetes and performed kubeadm init and join from the worker too. But when i run kubectl get nodes it gives the following response

the server doesn't have a resource type "nodes"

What might be the problem here? COuld not see anything in the /var/log/messages

Any hints here?

Comment: What does `kubectl cluster-info` say?

Comment: It just prints "Kubernetes master is running at http://localhost:8080"

Comment: [this seemingly relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42431749/gce-gke-kubectl-the-server-doesnt-have-a-resource-type-services?rq=1) implies it is an authentication problem -- what kind of auth is the cluster using?

Comment: Sorry i didnt get your question. I am following the guide mentioned here. https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/ .

Comment: Also on running kubectl version it gave the following error Client Version:  ...... Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks to me that the authentication credentials were not set correctly. Did you copy the kubeconfig file `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` to `~/.kube/config`? If you used kubeadm the API server should be configured to run on 6443, not in 8080. Could you also check that the KUBECONFIG variable is not set?

It would also help to increase the verbose level using the flag `--v=99`. Moreover, are you accessing from the same machine where the Kubernetes master components are installed, or are you accessing from the outside?

Comment: Yes. I have done that. And from netstat kube api server is listening on 6443 "tcp6       0    452 192.168.X.XXX:6443      192.168.X.XXX:55654     ESTABLISHED 25170/kube-apiserve" . KUBECONFIG variable is set but the conf file is empty. Should it be same as /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf ?

Comment: I am accessing the node directly not via a proxy. Its on my machine.

Comment: Yes. Copied /etc/kubernetes/conf to $HOME/admin.conf and issue got resolved.

Comment: Nice to know, do you consider the question answered?

Comment: Yes. Could you please also update that $HOME/admin.conf should have the same contents as conf in kubernetes and .kube/config. Not sure about the relevance of latter. But that is a separate discussion

Comment: In my case, i was missing the port 6443 in the end of server.

Answer (score 23):

In my case, I wanted to see the description of my pods.

When I used `kubectl describe postgres-deployment-866647ff76-72kwf`, the error said **error: the server doesn't have a resource type "postgres-deployment-866647ff76-72kwf"**.

I corrected it by adding `pod`, before the pod name, as follows:

```
kubectl describe pod postgres-deployment-866647ff76-72kwf
```

Answer (score 4):

I got this message when I was trying to play around with Docker-Desktop. I had previously been doing a few experiments with Google Cloud and run some `kubectl` commands for that. The result was that in my `~/.kube/config` file I still had stale config related to a now non-existent GCP cluster, and my default k8s context was set to that.

Try the following:

```sh
# Find what current contexts you have
kubectl config view
```

I get:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443
  name: docker-desktop
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: docker-desktop
    user: docker-desktop
  name: docker-desktop
current-context: docker-desktop
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: docker-desktop
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

So only one context now. If you have more than one context here, check that its the one you expect that is set to `current-context`.  If not change it with:

```sh
# Get rid of old contexts that you don't use 
kubectl config delete-context some-old-context

# Selecting the context that I have auth for
kubectl config use-context docker-desktop
```

Comment: When I run `kubectl config view`, I also get a namespace property that is different. Cluster, user, and name properties are almost the same with my credentials appended in user and name with a forward slash. I still have this error. I have made sure that I am in the right context. Highlight, confused between context and namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that "node" resource always exist in a Kubernetes cluster, this message means that `kubectl` connected to something else than a real cluster.

It is usually the sign of an error in the `~/.kube/config` file, in which case it tries by default to connect to localhost:8080
If you have anything running locally on that port, the it will return a 404 error at the kubectl call, which will interpret this as "Resource not found"

This will give errors like :

```
the server doesn't have a resource type "nodes"
the server doesn't have a resource type "pods"
the server doesn't have a resource type "services"
...
```