# When trying to connect jenkins and kubernetes, Jenkins job throws the following error

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

Started by user admin.
Running as SYSTEM.
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myjob
[myjob] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins8491647919256685444.sh
+ sudo kubectl get pods

error: the server doesn't have a resource type "pods"
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: This error usually comes when kube config is not properly configured. You probably do not have config file in root home

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the authentication credentials were not set correctly. Please copy the kubeconfig file  `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`  to  `~/.kube/config`? Also check that the KUBECONFIG variable is set.
It would also help to increase the verbose level using the flag  `--v=99`.

Please take a look: [kubernetes-configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46261686).